# On the browser, is there a way to programmatically create a calendar event for iCal without having to create an .ics file and download manually?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, icalendar

For my application, I need to programmatically create a calendar event and populate it on the user's local Mac `iCalendar` from the browser.

I found libraries that help me create an `.ics` file, and I have to manually download it and click on the downloaded file to populate that event on my calendar. But that's not what I want.

Is there a way to for me to create that calendar event and automatically populate it on `iCalendar` without having to go through steps of creating the .ics file and manually download it - using JavaScript on the browser?